# Cannot start JS application packed by Electron. Uncaught TypeError: require.nodeRequire is not a function

Tags: javascript, web-applications, electron

I packed our JS web-application by [Electron](http://electron.atom.io).
There is following error when I trying to start this packed application:

> text.js: Uncaught TypeError: require.nodeRequire is not a function

There is no function nodeRequire in our version of RequireJS.
As I understand version of RequireJSfor NodeJS is different from from version of RequireJSfor browsers.
What should I do to fix this problem?
Should I use in our web-application other version of RequireJS?
Or is it possible to configure Electron to avoid this error?

Comment: hi there, have you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Electron provides a config that worked for me.

```
// In the main process
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not actually in Electron or RequireJS, but in the [text.js loader](https://github.com/requirejs/text). Do you actually need that loader?

Answer (score 0):

Its how `require.js` is looking to load versus; how electron wants to load the webcontent. Mainly the `masterconfig` enviornment is not defined and so uses the problematic `nodeRequire`.

Following up on @Jose Rego's answer, which guided me in the right direction.

Provided you have the `nodeIntegration` set to `false`, you also need to ensure that the content is being loaded into the browser as an URL:

```
// Creazione della finestra del browser.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, 
                                 webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false } });
```

Then when you are loading your content, specify it to behave as a URL:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, `[STATIC_CONTENT_PATH]`),
  protocol: "file:",
  slashes: true
 })
);
```